# i dont want duplicate rows in my result

Tags: mysql

i have two table.in that table i have t6wo column each.if two column and their values are same in both the table then how to do inner join between those table.
my emp_code is primary key in another table and that table name is employee. 
and this emp_code is foreign key in actual_alldetails table and emp_time_tracking table.
actual_alldetails table:-

```
emp_code, date_id, card_id, wo, activity_id, quty, wastage, mcusage, actual_wastage
18, 151, 34, , 64, 275, 0, , 0
10, 152, 37, , 65, 19, 0, 3, 0
7, 152, 72, , 65, 4200, 4, , 0
```

emp_time_tracking table:-

```
emp_code, date_id, in_time, out_time
18, 151, 09:00:00, 18:00:00.0000
10, 152, 09:00:00, 18:00:00.0000
7, 152, 09:00:00, 18:00:00.0000
```

here emp_code and date_id is same and their value is also same. but when i am trying to execute my query like

```
select t.emp_code,t.date_id,t.in_time,t.out_time,a.card_id, a.wo, a.activity_id, a.quty, a.wastage, a.mcusage, a.actual_wastage from actual_alldetails a inner join emp_time_tracking t on t.emp_code=a.emp_code;
```

it will retrun all the rows from emp_time_tracking and  actual_alldetails.

please help to sovle my query.i dont want duplicate values from emp_time_tracking. i mean the emp_code and date_id  rows should not be repeated more than once.
please help me to come out of this.

Comment: You are looking for the `GROUP BY` clause. It always is a good idea to read the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

add this to the end of your query

```
GROUP BY emp_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of inner join try using "OUTER JOIN" and add "GROUP BY"

Answer (score 0):

Try below query-

```
SELECT t.emp_code,t.date_id,t.in_time,t.out_time,a.card_id, a.wo, a.activity_id, a.quty, a.wastage, a.mcusage, a.actual_wastage 
FROM actual_alldetails a 
INNER JOIN emp_time_tracking t ON t.emp_code=a.emp_code
GROUP BY t.emp_code,t.date_id;
```